# Can't verify signature witn Node.js Crypto, using key pairs

Tags: javascript, node.js, openssl, cryptojs

I've a very small code in nodejs where I sign a string and then try to verify it, using node crypto and key pairs generated with openssl. No matter what I try, the result is always "false", the signature can't be verified.

Generation of public/private key pairs:

```
openssl genrsa -out rsa_1024_priv.pem 1024

openssl rsa -in rsa_1024_priv.pem -out rsa_1024_pub.pem -outform PEM -pubout
```

The resultant keys are (I don't care made them public BTW):

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICXQIBAAKBgQDCtTEic76GBqUetJ1XXrrWZcxd8vJr2raWRqBjbGpSzLqa3YLv
VxVeK49iSlI+5uLX/2WFJdhKAWoqO+03oH4TDSupolzZrwMFSylxGwR5jPmoNHDM
S3nnzUkBtdr3NCfq1C34fQV0iUGdlPtJaiiTBQPMt4KUcQ1TaazB8TzhqwIDAQAB
AoGAM8WeBP0lwdluelWoKJ0lrPBwgOKilw8W0aqB5y3ir5WEYL1ZnW5YXivS+l2s
tNELrEdapSbE9hieNBCvKMViABQXj4DRw5Dgpfz6Hc8XIzoEl68DtxL313EyouZD
jOiOGWW5UTBatLh05Fa5rh0FbZn8GsHrA6nhz4Fg2zGzpyECQQDi8rN6qhjEk5If
+fOBT+kjHZ/SLrH6OIeAJ+RYstjOfS0bWiM9Wvrhtr7DZkIUA5JNsmeANUGlCrQ2
cBJU2cJJAkEA26HyehCmnCkCjit7s8g3MdT0ys5WvrAFO6z3+kCbCAsGS+34EgnF
yz8dDdfUYP410R5+9Cs/RkYesqindsvEUwJBALCmQVXFeKnqQ99n60ZIMSwILxKn
Dhm6Tp5Obssryt5PSQD1VGC5pHZ0jGAEBIMXlJWtvCprScFxZ3zIFzy8kyECQQDB
lUhHVo3DblIWRTVPDNW5Ul5AswW6JSM3qgkXxgHfYPg3zJOuMnbn4cUWAnnq06VT
oHF9fPDUW9GK3yRbjNaJAkAB2Al6yY0KUhYLtWoEpQ40HlATbhNel2cn5WNs6Y5F
2hedvWdhS/zLzbtbSlOegp00d2/7IBghAfjAc3DE9DZw
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDCtTEic76GBqUetJ1XXrrWZcxd
8vJr2raWRqBjbGpSzLqa3YLvVxVeK49iSlI+5uLX/2WFJdhKAWoqO+03oH4TDSup
olzZrwMFSylxGwR5jPmoNHDMS3nnzUkBtdr3NCfq1C34fQV0iUGdlPtJaiiTBQPM
t4KUcQ1TaazB8TzhqwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Then, this is my code for node:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var privateKey = '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n'+
'MIICXQIBAAKBgQDCtTEic76GBqUetJ1XXrrWZcxd8vJr2raWRqBjbGpSzLqa3YLv\n'+
'VxVeK49iSlI+5uLX/2WFJdhKAWoqO+03oH4TDSupolzZrwMFSylxGwR5jPmoNHDM\n'+
'S3nnzUkBtdr3NCfq1C34fQV0iUGdlPtJaiiTBQPMt4KUcQ1TaazB8TzhqwIDAQAB\n'+
'AoGAM8WeBP0lwdluelWoKJ0lrPBwgOKilw8W0aqB5y3ir5WEYL1ZnW5YXivS+l2s\n'+
'tNELrEdapSbE9hieNBCvKMViABQXj4DRw5Dgpfz6Hc8XIzoEl68DtxL313EyouZD\n'+
'jOiOGWW5UTBatLh05Fa5rh0FbZn8GsHrA6nhz4Fg2zGzpyECQQDi8rN6qhjEk5If\n'+
'+fOBT+kjHZ/SLrH6OIeAJ+RYstjOfS0bWiM9Wvrhtr7DZkIUA5JNsmeANUGlCrQ2\n'+
'cBJU2cJJAkEA26HyehCmnCkCjit7s8g3MdT0ys5WvrAFO6z3+kCbCAsGS+34EgnF\n'+
'yz8dDdfUYP410R5+9Cs/RkYesqindsvEUwJBALCmQVXFeKnqQ99n60ZIMSwILxKn\n'+
'Dhm6Tp5Obssryt5PSQD1VGC5pHZ0jGAEBIMXlJWtvCprScFxZ3zIFzy8kyECQQDB\n'+
'lUhHVo3DblIWRTVPDNW5Ul5AswW6JSM3qgkXxgHfYPg3zJOuMnbn4cUWAnnq06VT\n'+
'oHF9fPDUW9GK3yRbjNaJAkAB2Al6yY0KUhYLtWoEpQ40HlATbhNel2cn5WNs6Y5F\n'+
'2hedvWdhS/zLzbtbSlOegp00d2/7IBghAfjAc3DE9DZw\n'+
'-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----';

var publicKey = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n'+
'MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDCtTEic76GBqUetJ1XXrrWZcxd\n'+
'8vJr2raWRqBjbGpSzLqa3YLvVxVeK49iSlI+5uLX/2WFJdhKAWoqO+03oH4TDSup\n'+
'olzZrwMFSylxGwR5jPmoNHDMS3nnzUkBtdr3NCfq1C34fQV0iUGdlPtJaiiTBQPM\n'+
't4KUcQ1TaazB8TzhqwIDAQAB\n'+
'-----END PUBLIC KEY-----';

var signer = crypto.createSign('sha256');
signer.update('hola');
var sign = signer.sign(privateKey,'base64');

var verifier = crypto.createVerify('sha256');
verifier.update(sign);
var ver = verifier.verify(publicKey, sign,'base64');
console.log(ver);//<--- always false!
```

I've tried to use different algorithms and encoding. I've read the PEM files with "fs", no luck also. What am I missing? BTW, those keys works perfectly using npm URSA module, so I know the keys are ok (can't use ursa in my project). Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to verify the same data you signed: `verifier.update(sign);` should be `verifier.update('hola');`

Comment: Same code, didn't work for me. Any further suggestion?

Comment: @NinoFiliu Using the same code from the question and making the change I suggested results in `true` being printed to the console for me, I'm not sure why it would not work for you.

Comment: Bug corrected, I had a base64 - hex encoding mismatch