# Digital signature with timestamp in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, nestjs, digital-signature, trusted-timestamp

I need to verify Digital Signature for PDF file with Timestamp using Timestamp server like https://freetsa.org/tsr. In Nodejs or Nestjs have any library for this feature?

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48611041/using-node-js-crypto-to-verify-signatures) help?

Comment: I think no... I need a library like this [link](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-digitalsignature?_ga=2.10296246.2076360760.1636015881-1306415495.1635425023#adding-a-timestamp-to-pdf-document) but for nodejs or nestjs